# Can't download while connecting to the server on my network while on the phone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

quick question.
So this is the code:

```
export const downloadImage = async (state) => {
   try {
      let response = await axios.get(state.url, {
         responseType: "blob",
      });
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", state.url.slice(18));
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
   } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
};
```

**EDIT:** **Don't mind the slicing in the setAttribute and the state gives me the full info about the pic, url, text etc.**

It works prefectly, when i click download it downloads the img.

Since im using react when i do `npm start` it starts the live server and when i try to connect to it through my phone (which is on the same wifi network), and i connect with my IPv4 address and react port number (Example: 182.1281.12:3000) the image wont download...

So even tho the code is the same, it works on my PC and won't on my Phone, why is that?

Thanks.